# sublime command line open file in its own directory (in Linux)

Tags: sublimetext2

When a path to a file is given to sublime (from the command line), it opens the file in the last opened directory but I want to open the file in its own directory so I can navigate to others files too.

Sublime has also `-n` argument to open a file in new window but in this way, it won't load the whole directory.

Is there any argument or configuration in sublime to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The file is not opened “in the last opened directory,” how could it be? It is opened where it is. It is, however, placed in the sidebar into some place that exists there, which is probably what you meant.

Now, getting this distinction clear suggests a way to get what you want: Actually open the directory, `subl some/dir/`.

**EDIT:** Just to fold the discussion from the comments into here:

Sublime Text does not necessarily show directories in the sidebar, it allows you to group the project however you want.

To open a file and some enclosing directory, I guess the easiest way is this:

```
subl some/direcory some/directory/and/some/file.cc
```

Comment: No you are wrong. I've tested it. Right now I navigated to another directory and opened a file in command line but the sidebar had loaded ~ instead of that directory.

Comment: It means that it opens the file in its own directory but the sidebar is not that directory. sidebar is set to the last time a directory was opened.

Comment: I know. I was looking for a way to do both! opening a file and **also** showing its directory tree. ( I know I can open the directory and select the file manually but I don't want to do this )

Comment: **update** : I was wrong. It only opens an upper level directory. I think it's impossible to do so since sublime does not know where the root of the project is. ( it might be two level upper )

Comment: Let's not keep discussions in here. See my answer above: You should be able to just give it the project root.